# How can I fix it if I want both sides filled? bootstrap4 modal + grid(50:50)

Tags: bootstrap-4, django-templates

I applied grid in the bootstrap modal, but it doesn't split at 50:50

- Both sides should be filled in

but

[image]

- Is it wrong to divide by col?

  - Or is the card a problem?
- How can I fix it if I want both sides filled?
- Should I apply css additionally?

  - Or is there another way?

I hope the contents are almost full within the modal

If you know a good way please let me know

Thank you

Thanks for letting me know about css technology, jquery technology or html attribute values ​​or bootstrap's other grid systems that make the content full within the modal.

#### Code:

```
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl">
        <div class="modal-content">

            <h2 style="background-color:#00BFFF; padding:10px">할일 상세사항</h2>
            <!-- Modal Header -->
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title"> todo : {{ object.title }}</h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            </div>

            <!-- Modal body -->
            <div class="modal-body">
                {{ object.get_markdown_content | safe }}


                <div class="container">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                        <!-- insert form area -->
                        <div class="card border-info mb-3" style="width:100%">
                            <div class="card-header" style="background-color:orange; color:white">
                                <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
                                  summer_note
                                </a> &nbsp;
                                <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample2" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
                                  text_area
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-body">

                                <div class="comment_insert_area" style="background-color:white">

                                  <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
                                    <div class="card card-body">
                                        <form method="post" action="{{object.get_absolute_url}}new_comment/summer_note" id="comment_form_summer_note" class="hi">
                                            {% csrf_token %}
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                {{ comment_form | safe }}
                                            </div>
                                            <hr>
                                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" style="margin-right:20px;">Submit(summer_note)</button>
                                            <br>
                                        </form>
                                        {{ form.media }}
                                    </div>
                                  </div>

                                  <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample2">
                                    <div class="card card-body">
                                        <form method="post" action="{{object.get_absolute_url}}new_comment/text_area" id="comment_form_text_area" class="hi">
                                            {% csrf_token %}
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                {{ comment_form_text_area | crispy }}
                                            </div>
                                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary float-right btn-block" style="margin-right:20px;">Submit</button>
                                            <br>
                                        </form>
                                        {{ form.media }}
                                    </div>
                                  </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- insert form area end -->
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">

                        <!-- CodeProcess area -->
                        <div class="card border-danger mb-3" style="max-width: 80rem;">
                            <div class="card-header" style="background-color:black; color:white">
                                <h4>Code Process</h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-body">
                                {% for comment in comments_list_my.all %}

                                {% if comment.user_type == 1 %} <!-- 댓글 단 사람이 나일 경우 참고 -->

                                <table class="table table-bordered" id="comment_table_{{comment.id}}">

                                        {% if comment.author == request.user %}
                                        <tr bgcolor="#BFEFF2">
                                            <td>
                                                Step{{ forloop.counter }}
                                            </td>
                                            <td colspan="2">작성자 : <p style="color:blue;">{{comment.author}}</p></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td bgcolor="#BFEFF2">Title</td>
                                            <td colspan="3" bgcolor="#BFEFF2">
                                                <span id="todo_comment_title_output_{{comment.id}}">
                                                    {{comment.title}}
                                                </span>
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="" value="{{comment.title}}" id="todo_comment_title_{{comment.id}}" hidden>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        {% else %}
                                        <tr bgcolor="#FFEC77">
                                            <td>
                                                Step{{ forloop.counter }}
                                            </td>
                                            <td colspan="2">작성자 : <p style="color:black;">{{comment.author}}</p></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr bgcolor="#FFEC77">
                                            <td >title</td>
                                            <td colspan="3" >
                                                <span id="todo_comment_title_output_{{comment.id}}">
                                                    {{comment.title}}
                                                </span>
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="" value="{{comment.title}}" id="todo_comment_title_{{comment.id}}" hidden>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>

                                        {% endif %}

                                    <tr>
                                        <td>file_name</td>
                                        <td colspan="3">
                                            <span id="todo_comment_filename_output_{{comment.id}}">
                                                {{comment.file_name}}
                                            </span>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="" value="{{comment.file_name}}" id="todo_comment_file_name_{{comment.id}}" hidden>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                        <td>code</td>
                                        <td colspan="3">
                                            {% if comment.type.type_name == "summer_note" %}
                                            <!-- summernote일 경우 -->
                                            <span id="todo_comment_text_output_{{comment.id}}">
                                                {{ comment.text | safe }}
                                            </span>
                                            <textarea name="name" rows="10" cols="110" id="my_code_{{comment.id}}" class="summer_for_comment_update_copy_{{comment.id}}" hidden>{{comment.text}}</textarea>
                                            {% else %}
                                            <!-- textarea일 경우 -->
                                            <textarea name="name" rows="10" cols="110" id="{{comment.id}}" class="textarea_for_comment_update_{{comment.id}} form-control">{{comment.text}}</textarea>
                                            <button type="button" name="button" id="{{comment.id}}" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-danger copy_code">copy</button>
                                            {% endif %}
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td></td>
                                        <td colspan="2">
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary" onclick=location.href='{{comment.id}}/update' id={{comment.id}}>update</button>
                                            <!-- <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary updateTodoCommentButton" id={{comment.id}}>update2</button> -->

                                            {% if comment.author == request.user %}

                                            {% if comment.type.type_name == "summer_note" %}
                                            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary float-right comment_delete_button" id="{{comment.pk}}">delete</button> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary float-right comment_edit_complete_button_{{comment.pk}} comment_edit_complete_button_for_summernote" id="{{comment.pk}}" hidden>업데이트 완료(summernote)</button> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary float-right comment_edit_form_button comment_edit_form_button_{{comment.pk}}" id="{{comment.pk}}">edit_mode</button>
                                            {% else %}
                                            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary float-right comment_delete_button" id="{{comment.pk}}">delete</button> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary float-right comment_edit_complete_button_{{comment.pk}} comment_edit_complete_button_for_text_area" id="{{comment.pk}}" >업데이트 textarea</button> &nbsp;&nbsp;
                                            {% endif %}



                                            {% endif %}


                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td colspan="3" border="0"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                                <br>
                                {% else %}

                                {% endif %}
                                {% endfor %}
                                <div class="reply_list"></div>

                            </div>


                        </div>
                        <!-- CodeProcess area end -->


                    </div>
                  </div>

            <!-- Modal footer -->
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use container. container makes some padding space on both sides, and it comes with max-with on each media query.

You would better use d-flex, or you can set w-50 on wrapper without .container.

Comment: d-flex was valid Thanks for solving the problem